# How to replace normal InputMethod/Keyboard with my own created keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have created my own InputMethod/Keyboard, but I don't know how to show up this instead of the normal InputMethod/Keyboard in my app, so that for clicking any `EditText` it shows up. (My Keyboard is only for my app, not as system keyboard)

Do I have to handle `Keyboard`,`KeyboardView`, `InputConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Let me know if this helps you.